# how to show red border in input field on button In angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could you please tell how to show red border in the input field on a button in angularJs . Currently, the red border is displayed when the application load. Actually, I added ng-required validation on my form .but I want this only work after button click here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/zL0cueTJN6xqxC4LzhOd?p=preview

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': myform[key].$invalid}">
                                    <input type="text" name="{{key}}" class="form-control" ng-model="value.value" ng-required="value.required">
                                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable `$scope.isSubmitClicked=false;` in scope and make it `true` in `submit()`

```
$scope.isSubmitClicked = false;
$scope.submit = function ($event) {           
    $scope.isSubmitClicked = true;
};
```

Then

```
<input type="text" name="{{key}}" class="form-control" ng-model="value.value" ng-required="value.required && isSubmitClicked">
```

Comment: can we check form is valid or not on button click ?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can check the fields in the submit function

Comment: how could you please tell me how . ?

Comment: I think it is already hapenning. If the form is not valid i.e. any required field value is missing, it is showing the input required (red color)

Comment: but i want to check using javascript myform.valid() ?? give true or false ?